# Problem in including STL header files

Tags: c++, stl

I have created Dialog Based application in MFC (VS 2008).When I do "#include" in Dlg.cpp it showing following error.

Is Some Component is  missing in the VS 2008 Installation

```
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\xmemory(43) : 
error C2665: 'operator new' : none of the 5 overloads could convert all the argument types

1>        c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\new.h(85): could be 'void *operator new(size_t,const std::nothrow_t &) throw()'

1>        c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\new.h(93): or       'void *operator new(size_t,void *)'

1>        while trying to match the argument list '(const char [70], int)'

1>        c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\xmemory(145) : see reference to function template instantiation '_Ty *std::_Allocate<char>(size_t,_Ty *)' being compiled

1>        with

1>        [
1>            _Ty=char
1>        ]

1>        c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\xmemory(144) : while compiling class template member function 'char *std::allocator<_Ty>::allocate(std::allocator<_Ty>::size_type)'

1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=char
1>        ]

1>        c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\xstring(2216) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::allocator<_Ty>' being compiled

1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=char
1>        ]

1>Build log was saved at "file://c:\Users\Public\Documents\Proj\STL1\STL1\Debug\BuildLog.htm"
1>STL1 - 1 error(s), 0 warning(s)
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: Sounds like something is wrong with your code. We'd need to look at it to say more.

Comment: there is no code If i am including #include <map> or #include <vector> is showing this error.This means If I am Including any STL header file it is showing error.

Comment: Likely a problem with new conflicting with the Microsoft specific DEBUG new.  Does your file have a `#define new DEBUG_NEW`?

Comment: It is the nature of template errors that they are hard to interpret. Trust me when I say there's nothing wrong with the library headers, it all started somewhere in *your* code.

Comment: @Chad Yes it is there.Can You explain the reason and Tell what to do.

Comment: @Mark Ransom: I have Just Created MFC Dilaog based application and when I included the #include<map> it is showing this error.If I comment this line it is compiling correctly.There is no Additional code.

Comment: @Chad: I tried with commenting #define new DEBUG_NEW.now it is working fine.Can Somebody tell what is the reason for this.

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you compiling with.  I remember this being problematic in the past, but I cannot reproduce with VS2010.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Any STL includes in your MFC project should be included prior to the definition of DEBUG_NEW.  This was a problem in the past (no longer seems to be, as I cannot reproduce it in VS 2010).

```
// myfile.cpp
#ifdef _DEBUG
#define new DEBUG_NEW
#endif

// This will cause the error
#include <vector>
```

Whereas

```
// myfile.cpp
// will work OK
#include <vector>

#ifdef _DEBUG
#define new DEBUG_NEW
#endif
```

`DEBUG_NEW` is a microsoft specific extension that helps to find memory leaks in debug versions of the application.  It can be very useful in certain cases.

It's defined in afx.h as:

```
void* AFX_CDECL operator new(size_t nSize, LPCSTR lpszFileName, int nLine);
#define DEBUG_NEW new(THIS_FILE, __LINE__)`
```

It's helps to provide tracking of memory allocated and when a leak is detected will give you the file and line number where the allocation took place.

Comment: Yeah Chad Your are right I tried Including before      #ifdef _DEBUG
#define new DEBUG _NEW
#endif   It is Working Fine Thanks.

Comment: Fantastic psychic debugging, Chad. Maybe Microsoft put a `#undef DEBUG_NEW` at the top of each header file?

Comment: Not really psychic -- I'd been bitten by this in the past (in my MFC days on Visual Studio 6).  You could `#undef DEBUG_NEW`, but as I said above it does have it's benefits and makes finding memory leaks in MFC  applications almost trivial.

Comment: hate to ask, but is there a Mac equivalent?  I'm finding that including STL within a project is giving me lots of problems

Comment: I don't work much with Macs, so I can't say.  Sounds like you should open a new question with your specific issue, as this is specific to Microsoft Visual Studio (not that Mac couldn't have a similar issue).